# Retrieve post ID from "querying" URL

Tags: posts, permalinks, urls, id

*Disclaimer: I can't post more than two links, yet...*

I know there are many similar questions, but none of the solutions work for me.

My problem is that with the Live Composer Plugin (wordpress.org/plugins/live-composer-page-builder/) the `url_to_postid()` function does not return a post id for Live Composer's custom post types, e. g. "Partners", "Project", "Staff". The URL of the permalink for a project named "Testproject" by default has the form `http://localhost/wordpress/?dslc_projects=testproject`. This does not get resolved by `url_to_postid()` into a valid post ID.

The workaround is to set the permalink structure to something other than the default "plain" setting. Then `url_to_postid()` in fact does correctly resolve even LC's custom post types.

However I do not trust the user to remember this workaround. Heck, I don't even trust myself. Hence, I'd like to know, if there is a way to resolve the type of URL above.

I'm new to WordPress, therefore I have not yet messed around with the database directly, have not implemented custom taxonomies and have not provided custom rewrite rules. I don't even know, what the type of URL like `http://localhost/wordpress/?dslc_projects=testproject` is called, although it seems to me to provoke a query in the database to match the `dslc_projects` attribute to `testproject`.
I'd love to know if this type of URL has a name, so I can google it and learn about it. Also, if someone knows how to get the post ID using those URLs that would be even awesomer. :)

---

**Edit:** I've now probably found a little bug in `url_to_postid()`. The functions returns when it hits the [following if-clause](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.6/src/wp-includes/rewrite.php#L509) :

```
// Check to see if we are using rewrite rules
    $rewrite = $wp_rewrite->wp_rewrite_rules();

// Not using rewrite rules, and 'p=N' and 'page_id=N' methods failed, so we're out of options
if ( empty($rewrite) )
    return 0;
```

I assume this is a bug, since apparently there can be rewrite rules on custom post type URLs, which should be detected here.

It is reported as ticket [#38041](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/38041).

Comment: If you have a question about the inner workings of a third party plugin, you have a better chance of getting an answer at its author's forum

Comment: Isn't this type of URL also what is used with the plain permalink option such as `http://localhost/wordpress/?p=123`? Only that that it is another attribute, `p`? If it is so, then maybe it is possible to query the database for the attribute `dslc_projects`. Do you know any ressources on that?

Answer (score -1):

> Try This Code

```
 $latest = new WP_Query( array (
    'post_type'    =>'your-post-type-name',
    'post_status'  =>'publish',
    'orderby'               => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page'        => 3
    ));

    while ( $latest -> have_posts() ) : $latest -> the_post();
    echo the_ID();
    endwhile;
```

Comment: I don't understand, what the code is doing. Is it loading the pages and then getting the ID? Also, is it possible to get the post type from the URL?

Comment: simple you can define post type on 'post_type' => 'name of post type slug'

Comment: This seems to be loading the the post information into the $post global, which seems "overkill". (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#more-information) Is there a way to search the database for the attribute?